# LEGO EV3 Brick Type Data File not found

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

So this morning, I was going to build something with my EV3 kit, when I turned on the brick, the brick said 'Type data File not found'. Then I plugged in my touch sensor and all the motors in their proper place, they all said unknown, only the ultrasonic, gyro and color sensor were working. I really don't understand what is wrong here, so please, give me your ideas. So I can fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The type data file is probably [this file](https://github.com/mindboards/ev3sources/blob/master/lms2012/lms2012/Linux_AM1808/sys/settings/typedata.rcf). It contains definitions for non-UART sensors, which explains why the motors and touch sensor do not work but the other sensors do.

I'm not sure how it could be missing since it normally isn't exposed to the user (maybe the flash memory got corrupted or some 3rd-party tool was used to delete the file). You could try flashing the firmware again. If that doesn't work, contact LEGO customer support.